# Can I "un-blurryfy" or "un-smallify" my laptop display in a 3-monitor configuration?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-quadro

I have a 3-monitor setup: a Dell Precision M4700 (max resolution 1920x1080) and two Dell P2210 monitors (resolutions 1680x1050). I'm running my external monitors at their native resolutions, but running the laptop display at its native resolution makes stuff very small in relationship to the other two monitors.

To get consistent sizing between all 3 monitors, I have to put the laptop monitor display at 1366x768, but this makes the display on the laptop monitor pretty blurry.

Is there any way to keep the three displays consistent with each other size-wise without sacrificing picture clarity on the laptop monitor?

Comment: 1) Keep the resolution of a LCD on it native resolution or on whole multiples of native resolution (e.g. 960x600 on a 1920x1200 screen). 2) In windows can use the DPI settings to render things larger. I am not sure if you can apply that to a single screen though. (and making everything on all three screens equally bigger does not solve the problem).

Comment: Seems like the solution is to set your monitors resolution to 1920x1080 instead of 1680x1050

Comment: @Ramhound - 1920x1080 is not a native resolution for those monitors. Indeed, it doesn't look very good..

Comment: @DangKhoa - What sort of graphics card do you have?  Sounds like you are up the creek with a paddle if your monitors do not support the native resolution your laptop display supports.

Comment: @Ramhound - it's an nVidia Quadro K2000M.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this cannot be solved using the built-in tools of Windows.
The natural solution of changing the DPI does not work in Windows because it is per-system
and so applies to all the monitors. Only Linux has that capacity for the moment.

It is possible that third-party software could create differing profiles per monitor.
You could try the trial versions of the two leading products, [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)
and [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/), although the hopes are slim as both this [UltraMon thread](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/messages.asp?Topic=11870&tmpl=UltraMon,%20UltraMon%22;%20BB-code%20not%20working;)
and [DisplayFusion thread](http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/dpi-settings-per-monitor/?ID=e8bc20dd-7907-48e7-b2f9-a9f2c450558b) decline that capability.

There is a possibility that this might improve in Windows 8.1 (Blue), as described
in the article
[In Blue: Automatic Desktop Display Scaling](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/blue-automatic-desktop-display-scaling).